# How to invoke long range correlations among the onsite energies in a 1D lattice theoretically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am trying to find some literature which tells me how to prescribe the on site energies in a lattice such that they have a long range correlation. I want to generate separate sets of those energies randomly in each realization.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to find a formula for the on-site energies of each site on the lattice, so that the energies have a long range correlation among them, say  $<e_i e_j> \approx (j-i)^{-k}$.

Comment: Presumably there would be many possible solutions to such a constraint so I'm doubtful of an analytical solution. A numerical approach, however, would be to use Monte Carlo (possibly with annealing).

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly give the link to a resource  where I can learn to use to create energies with annealing, or if it is basic enough write one line to make me understand how to work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of how you might achieve this numerically with a Monte Carlo method.

Suppose you desire $\langle e_ie_j\rangle\approx f_{ij}$. Define some metric $U=\|\langle e_ie_j\rangle - f_{ij}\|$ to measure how 'close' you are to such a correlation.

*Step 1:* Begin with a random array $\{e_i\}$.

*Step 2:* For each i: perturb $e_i\rightarrow e_i+\delta$ with a random $\delta$ and evaluate the resultant change in $U$, call it $\Delta U$. You accept this change with probability $\min(1, \exp(-\Delta U/T))$, otherwise you reject it.

Repeat Step 2 until $U$ becomes sufficiently small, and record the configuration $\{e_i\}$ that minimises $U$.

Note the $T$ parameter above. When $T\to\infty$, all changes will be accepted (random walk) whereas when $T\to 0$ you have direct minimisation of $U$.
Simulated annealing involves starting with a large $T$ and then gradually decreasing it over many iterations.

Comment: One doubt: Do we have to repeat step 2, given a fixed i, for all j's ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; there's no loop over j. For step 2 you simply update each and every $i$, each time re-evaluating $U$ and accepting with the above probability.